# android icon in custom dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, icons

I have implemented the following code for the custom dialog box, and hope to also put an icon in the title bar, but fails. The dialog box pops up without any icon on the left.

```
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(First.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog1.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
        dialog1.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND); 
        dialog1.setCancelable(true);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        dialog1.show();
        dialog1.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.lemon1_fw);
```

I have tried some comments found online and seems there is no difference to put `setFeatureDrawableResource` either before or after `.show()`;

How could it be solved? many thanks!!

Comment: you set dialog with no title bar! where is the position of drawing icon? on title bar? and i think there is better solution! make the custom view for dialog and set it with setcontentView.and you can place icon every where u want

Comment: Hi Leon_SFS, I would like to add the icon to the title of the dialog box, not the title bar, thanks!

Comment: i recommended you to create custom layout for your dialog box,its very simple and handy @pearmak

Comment: thanks! i have done that! could you please make your comment as answer? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a simple sample for getting custom layout for dialog

```
private Dialog m_ShowAction;
//in onCreate
m_ShowAction = new Dialog(Contacts_List_Activity.this);
m_ShowAction.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
m_ShowAction.setContentView(R.layout.popup_action_dialog);
m_ShowAction.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
......

//inflate your control on custom Dialog layout like this
ListView lstActionList = (ListView) m_ShowAction.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

and you can set onclick or anything for any control on custom layout like the normal activity layout

at the end call `m_ShowAction.show();`